# Customzing ticks/dates on horizontal axis - Google Charts via wpDataTables

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm inserting a Google line chart on my site via the WP plugin wpDataTables (wpDataCharts). I'm using Elementor to build the site. You can see the chart [here](https://aialphalab.com/fund-test) a little down on the page.

wpDataTables has a limited number of chart options you can adjust, probably based on what the Google API allows. If you want to make further changes, you can use the callback function.

I have used the callback function to remove the padding Google adds to the chart as standard (which makes the chart fill out only 50% of the container) and made the tooltip include both graphs. The working code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load',function(){ 
    if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; } 
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[4] = function(obj){ 
        obj.options.chartArea = {left:135,top:30,width:'100%',height:'75%'};
        obj.options.focusTarget = ['category'];
    }
});
</script>
```

However, I want to control the ticks/dates shown on the horizontal axis. I have been looking in the Google API documentation and found the object I think I need ([hAxis.ticks](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart)), but I just can't make it work. No matter what I do, it has zero impact on the dates shown.

Here's my best bet at the code, but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load',function(){ 
    if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; } 
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[4] = function(obj){ 
        obj.options.hAxis.ticks = hAxis: {
                    ticks: [{v: new Date(2020, 1, 1), f: '2020'}, {v: new Date(2021, 1, 1), f: '2021'}, {v: new Date(2022, 1, 1), f: '2022'}, {v: new Date(2023, 1, 1), f: '2023'}]

   }
});
</script>
```

Any help is much appreciated. Be aware that I have no coding background, so I'm probably making a lot of "easy" mistakes, getting the coding lingo all wrong etc. Bear with me please :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code snippet you provided, it appears that you have an extra hAxis: inside the ticks array. Try removing that and see if it works:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).on('load',function(){ 
    if( typeof wpDataChartsCallbacks == 'undefined' ){ wpDataChartsCallbacks = {}; } 
    wpDataChartsCallbacks[4] = function(obj){ 
        obj.options.hAxis.ticks = [{v: new Date(2020, 1, 1), f: '2020'}, {v: new Date(2021, 1, 1), f: '2021'}, {v: new Date(2022, 1, 1), f: '2022'}, {v: new Date(2023, 1, 1), f: '2023'}];
    }
});
</script>
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Awesome!!! It works, a big thanks!

Would you by any chance know how I get each year to center under each of the vertical gridlines? Right now the year/text starts at the gridline - if it makes sense.

https://aialphalab.com/fund-test/

Comment: Glad to be of any help. Would be great if you can accept / upvote my answer as well. Thanks

Comment: Sure, have marked is as answer, but need more reputation to upvote. Would you by any chance know how I get each year to center under each of the vertical gridlines? Right now the year/text starts at the gridline - if it makes sense.